# Show that the Riemann Zeta Function is continuous for s>1.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^s$. Show that $\zeta(s)$ is continuous for $s>1$.

Comment: MathJax tip: Use \zeta.

Comment: Hint. Uniform convergence preserves continuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
for $x>1$,  take $a\in (1,x)$ .
we have

$$\forall t\in [a,+\infty)\;\;\; \frac{1}{n^t}\leq\frac{1}{n^a}$$.

- for each $n>0, t\mapsto \frac{1}{n^t}$ is continuous at $[a,+\infty).$
- $\sum \frac{1}{n^t}$ converges uniformly at $[a,+\infty)$

thus,  the sum function zeta is continuous at

each $x>1$.